# Minitoc in the margin of a tufte-book

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte, minitoc

I am using the `tufte-book` documentclass to typeset notes. I'd like a `minitoc` in the margin at the start of each chapter. The (hacky) approach I turned to first is to use `\marginnote{\minitoc}`, however with long titles the hbox overflows and it gets cut off. Similarly with no long title, the contents box seems to extend over the page still.

Is this an appropriate way to set a `minitoc` into the margin of a `tufte-book` and, if so, how may I force the `minitoc` to stay within the page geometry?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[openany]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem?}

\marginnote{\minitoc}

\section{Ipsum}

\blindtext

\section{A long title, perhaps pondering the meaning of life}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

### MWE output

The warnings overleaf raises appear to be irrelevant to the problem:

- "Marginpar on page 1 moved", which may be the problem; a search of similar problems on TeXOverflow seems to show it occurs when the marginnote is moved between compiles, which doesn't happen here.
- "Package bibentry Warning: You have used `\nobibliography*` without a following `\bibliography`. You may not be able to run BibTeX."

[image: sameple output from overleaf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two warnings you get are nothing to worry about. The second one just comes from a package that is loaded by `tufte-book`. The first one tells you that the margin note is now at its correct place, but wasn’t when the document was compiled the first time.

The `\documentclass` you use also styles tables of contents. But it has a `notoc` option to prevent this. Because you probably don’t want such a big font size and large line width in your margin, you should use this option. Furthermore, it is necessary to place the mini TOC in a `minipage` with the width of the margin. It is also probably better to set `\mtcindent` to zero.

```
\documentclass[openany,notoc]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setlength{\mtcindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem?}

\marginnote{%
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \minitoc%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\section{Ipsum}

\blindtext

\section{A long title, perhaps pondering the meaning of life}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this did it! :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `etoc`:

```
\documentclass[openany]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsetstyle{section}
  {\parindent -1em \parskip 1ex}
  {\leftskip 1em}
  {\etocnumber
   \etocname\nobreak\hspace{2em}
   \etocpage\par}
  {}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}
  {\parindent -1em \parskip 1ex}
  {\leftskip 2em}
  {\etocname\nobreak\hspace{2em}
   \etocpage\par}
  {}
\etocsettocstyle{\normalfont\normalsize}{}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem?}

\marginnote{\localtableofcontents}

\section{Ipsum}

\blindtext

\section{A long title, perhaps pondering the meaning of life}

\blindtext

\subsection{A subsection}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]